Enrich records/logs with kubernetes metadata for custom log file locations inside k8s pod using fluentbit with cloudwatch
I am using the EKS Observability addon, which combines Fluent Bit and CloudWatch log groups, as my Kubernetes logging solution. Logs written to stdout and stderr by my application are successfully forwarded to the CloudWatch log group, complete with Kubernetes metadata (e.g., namespace name, pod name, and container name).
However, my application also writes logs to a file inside the pod, which is mounted using an emptyDir volume. The file's location on the worker node is /var/lib/kubelet/pods/*/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/hostpath-vol/logs/app.log. I have configured Fluent Bit to include this custom file location for log forwarding to CloudWatch. While the logs are being sent to the CloudWatch log group, they lack the Kubernetes metadata (such as namespace, pod name, and container name). It's getting very difficult to identify which deployment has written logs to cloudwatch loggroup without k8s metadata.
Below is the Fluent Bit ConfigMap configuration I am using.
apiVersion: v1
data:
application-log.conf: |
[INPUT]
Name                tail
Tag                 application.*
Exclude_Path        /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*, /var/log/containers/fluent-bit*, /var/log/containers/aws-node*, /var/log/containers/kube-proxy*
Path                /var/log/containers/*.log
Parser_Firstline    multiline
Multiline           on
DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_container.db
Mem_Buf_Limit       50MB
Skip_Long_Lines     On
Refresh_Interval    10
Rotate_Wait         30
storage.type        filesystem
Read_from_Head      ${READ_FROM_HEAD}
[INPUT]
  Name                tail
  Path                /var/lib/kubelet/pods/*/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/hostpath-vol/logs/app.log
  Tag                 customfilelogs.*
  multiline.parser    docker, cri
  DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_custom_file.db
  Refresh_Interval    5
  Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
  Read_from_Head      ${READ_FROM_HEAD}

[FILTER]
  Name                kubernetes
  Match               application.*
  Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
  Kube_Tag_Prefix     application.var.log.containers.
  Merge_Log           On
  Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
  K8S-Logging.Parser  On
  K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
  Labels              Off
  Annotations         Off
  Use_Kubelet         On
  Kubelet_Port        10250
  Buffer_Size         0

[FILTER]
  Name                kubernetes
  Match               customfilelogs.*
  Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
  Kube_Tag_Prefix     customfilelogs.
  Merge_Log           On
  Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
  K8S-Logging.Parser  On
  K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
  Labels              Off
  Annotations         Off
  Use_Kubelet         On
  Kubelet_Port        10250
  Buffer_Size         0

[OUTPUT]
  Name                cloudwatch_logs
  Match               application.*
  region              ${AWS_REGION}
  log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/application
  log_stream_prefix   fallback-stream
  log_retention_days  30
  auto_create_group   true
  log_stream_template $kubernetes['namespace_name']
  extra_user_agent    container-insights

[OUTPUT]
  Name                cloudwatch_logs
  Match               customfilelogs.*
  region              ${AWS_REGION}
  log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/customruntimelogs
  log_stream_prefix   fallback-stream
  log_retention_days  30
  auto_create_group   true
  log_stream_template $kubernetes['namespace_name']
  extra_user_agent    container-insights

